# I am unable to access routes in production build of my react app

Tags: reactjs

My local build had routing working well and good, once when I created a production build I am unable to access routes in my production build

I have tried all the solutions which I have come across

```
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
function render(component) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/constlist" component={ConstituencyList}/>
                <Route path="/addRep" component={AddRep}/>
                <Route exact path="/roundList/:id" component={RoundList}/>
                <Route exact path="/updateVotes/:cid/:rid" component={UpdateVotes}/>
                <Route exact path="/analysis/:id" component={AnalysisPage}/>
                <Route exact path="/replist" component={RepList}/>
                <Route exact path="/admin" component={AdminLogin}/>
                <Route exact path="/addCandidate" component={AddCandidate}/>
                <Route exact path="/homepage" component={HomePage}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
}

render(<App />);
```

Actual output: Routing must have been enabled

Comment: Where are you deploying it? Is the server setup to handle single page applications, with proper routing?

Comment: I deployed the production build in my local machine, My local build seems to work well whereas the production build provides 404 error once I navigate through the application in production

Answer (score 2):

This issue is not specific to your code. But it happens with any SPA hosted on a web server.

Cause: When you try to hit xyz.com/page1 then webserver assumes that you are trying to get index.html inside 'page1' folder inside your root. That does not work because you don't have 'page1' folder in your root. So webserver gives 404 error. This mostly happens when you directly try to open xyz.com/page1 but it works well when you first open xyz.com and then navigate to xyz.com/page1 . This is becuase when you first load xyz.com your react router has bootstrapped in the browser hand subsequent routing is taken care of.

Resolution: You need to tell webserver to always default to your root's index.html. So when it does not find a folder while looking for index.html inside it, it takes root's index.html. This can be done by changing webserver's config. For example in nginx you can do this:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Other webservers may have different setting/config to achieve the same.